# Dynamic override class method in Ruby module

Tags: ruby, inheritance, prepend

Is it possible to dynamically override a class method in Ruby?

I have a `ErrorHandler` module which should dynamically create a class method with a given name and do the same as the method it is overriding:

```
module ErrorHandler
    def self.handle_error_from(method_name)
      define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*arguments|
        begin
          super(*arguments)
        rescue
          return "Handler return"
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The above module is `prepended` to another module.

```
module AnotherModule
      prepend ErrorHandler

      ErrorHandler.handle_error_from :create

      def self.create(params)
       # Code here
      end
end
```

The above example triggers the ErrorHandler but it does not override it with the created method.

I've seen this be done with instance methods, but is there a limitation when it is class methods?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code.

1. With `prepend` and `self` in your module you will actually define the wrapper method on your module. You can try this with using your code and add a `puts ErrorHandler.methods` after the `handle_error_from` and you will see it has a `create` method defined. The reason is that self is `ErrorHandler` in this case.
2. You need to define the wrapper method after the original method is defined.

See here a full example.

```rb
module ErrorHandler
    def handle_error_from(method_name)
      define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*arguments|
        begin
          super(*arguments)
        rescue
          puts  "Handler return"
        end
      end
    end
end


class Foo
  extend ErrorHandler

  def self.create
    raise "error"
  end
  handle_error_from "create"
end

Foo.create
```

Comment: The above example only kinda works. The super(*arguments) in the ErrorHandler module for some reason always throws an error. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you give an example? Please note that I have `raise 'error'` in the `create` method to show it's working.

Comment: It is exactly as you do above. However it's triggered via a AWS Lambda and not Foo.create. You think the setup makes a difference?